# Specifying "folder" option does not upload image to folder in Cloudinary

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm having some difficulty getting uploads to the correct folder. If I specify:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(filePath, {
  folder: 'test-directory'
});
```

I'm following the Node integration guide at: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload

I created the "test-directory" ahead of time. The image uploads successfully, but always goes to the root of my media library.

I have "auto create folders" enabled in my account settings.

Here's a sample upload response from Cloudinary:

```
{
  public_id: 'we1yjvlpxc1qtuf1oaqe',
  version: 1503236713,
  signature: '37edbc2b19ea72b75298acce8075f9e8ddb12d09',
  width: 675,
  height: 37,
  format: 'jpg',
  resource_type: 'image',
  created_at: '2017-08-20T13:45:13Z',
  tags: [],
  bytes: 602,
  type: 'upload',
  etag: 'b5522ae652340881b213c46c035d0aed',
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/alsoicode/image/upload/v1503236713/we1yjvlpxc1qtuf1oaqe.jpg',
  secure_url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/alsoicode/image/upload/v1503236713/we1yjvlpxc1qtuf1oaqe.jpg',
  original_filename: 'test_r6_c1'
}
```

I have also tried adding the folder name to the `public_id` option, but that hasn't worked either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the `public_id` returned in the upload response?

Comment: @Maor.G I've added a complete upload response.

Comment: Cloudinary also doesn't seem to be respecting other options like `use_filename`, as the uploaded resources all have automatically generated filenames. The uploads are successful, but no options are applied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `v2` to have the upload parameters' order as (file, options, callback) -

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(filePath, {
 folder: 'test-directory',
 use_filename: true
});
```

Without it the order is (file, callback, options) -

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(filePath,function(res){console.log(res);},{
 folder: 'test-directory',
 use_filename: true
})
```

Comment: That's got it. Thank you! I'm not sure how I managed to miss the `.v2.` in the documentation, but it's right there. I sincerely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

- upload parameters' order as (file, options, callback) *

  ```
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(
            file,
            {
                folder: 'directory',
                use_filename: true
            },
            function (error, result) {
                if (result.url) {
                    resolve({ url: result.url })
                } else {
                    reject({ message: "image upload fail", error })
                }
            },

        );
  ```

Comment: That order is correct only with `v2`, as @Maor.G mentioned in the above answer.
You can do `var cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2` and then use `cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, options, callback)`, instead of explicitly adding the  `v2` on every invocation of `cloudinary`.

Comment: @ekt yes above answer is Without it the order is (file, callback, options) and my answer is upload parameters order as (file, options, callback)

Answer (score 0):

`cloudinary` upload function expects three parameters,
`cloudinary.uploader.upload(path,options,callback)`
if you didn't declare the three parameters this way, `cloudinary` will understand your folder path as callback not an option, thus it won't understand the path nor the folder that you are pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary upload function looks like the following one, options contains different fields including `folder` field.

```
upload(file: string, options?: UploadApiOptions, callback?: UploadResponseCallback)
```

For those who use `upload_stream` can refer to the following example method

```
  uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<CloudinaryResponse> {
    return new Promise<CloudinaryResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
      const uploadStream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
        {
          folder: 'folderName',
        },
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          resolve(result);
        },
      );

      streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer).pipe(uploadStream);
    });
  }
```